# CakePHP doesn't respect model config

Tags: php, cakephp

I have a model (CrewModel.php):

```
<?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
class Crew extends AppModel {
    public $useTable = 'crew23424';

    public $validate = array(
        'crew_id' => array('rule'    => 'isUnique')
    );

    function __construct()
    {
        echo "asd"; exit;
    }
    public function save(){
        echo "exit";
        exit;
    }
    public function beforeSave()
    {
        echo "exit";
        exit;
    }
}
```

But my config in model (useTable) is not respecting, Cake still uses tablename "crews" and when I do `var_dump($this->Crew);` I have the following reponse: http://pastebin.com/2QsFeUQa

None of my functions are executed (`save()`, `beforeSave()`... of course when I execute `$this->Crew->save()` etc)

How to make it work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In CakePHP if we do not define  Model for our Table and still execute query using
 `$this->Model->query()` or something related to model. CakePHP will create model object for us.

So you have to change your model file name as per CakePHP naming convention.

This could be the reason your $useTable variable is not working as you expected.

Comment: Glad I could help you ;) have fun coding

Answer (score 0):

Please Change The Model name to Crew.php I think will Work